# Items inside a ListView - android

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, listview

i have a list view which contains 2 text views and 3 buttons, and i want to do something when click on one of thoses buttons but where to write OnclickListener of thoses buttons ?!

my java class

```
       public class AdminGlossary extends ListActivity {


// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products = "http://www.lamia.byethost18.com/get_all_glossaries.php";
private static final String url_delete_product = "http://www.lamia.byethost18.com/delete_product.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
private static final String TAG_PID = "ID_glossary";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_DES = "description";
private static final String TAG_CHA = "ID_chapter";

String pid="0";


// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_glossary);


    // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    /*lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    EditProductActivity.class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });*/

}

// Response from Edit Product Activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received 
        // means user edited/deleted product
        // reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AdminGlossary.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String des = c.getString(TAG_DES);
                    String cha = c.getString(TAG_CHA);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_DES, des);
                    map.put(TAG_CHA, cha);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        NewProductActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AdminGlossary.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item_2, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                TAG_NAME, TAG_DES, TAG_CHA},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.des, R.id.cha });

                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }}
```

my list_item_2.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="106dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:text="@string/ddd"
    android:textSize="17dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/des"
    android:layout_width="76dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/name"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:text="@string/dd"
    android:textSize="17dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cha"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/des"
    android:background="@null"
    android:text="@string/d"
    android:textColor="#0000ff"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/deletee"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/name"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Button"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/editt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cha"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/deletee"
    android:text="Button"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

can someone please help me with this ?

thank you ..:)

Comment: You can write it in the Adapter class.

Comment: @Ranjith do i write the adapter class or its already there ?

Comment: You have created a custom listview, so you should already have the Baseadapter class

Comment: @Ranjith i didnt create an adapter .. sorry but what i should write in the adapter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a a couple ways to do this:

1.) Set the "android:onClick" attribute for each button in your layout file to the method that you want to call. It would look something like this:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/cha"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/des"
android:background="@null"
android:text="@string/d"
android:textColor="#0000ff"
android:textSize="15sp" 
android:onClick="<methodname>"/>
```

2.) Set the onClickListener for each button when it is generated in the ListView's adapter.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i dont have listview adapter .. sorry but can you tell me why i need it and what i should write in it ?

Comment: Its used for efficiency purposed really. The benefits really show up in lists that have a large number of items. The adapter allows the views within the ListView to be reused and recycled once they are no longer visible on screen after scrolling. Instead of loading n objects when the ListView is created without an adapter, the adapter only loads the views that are visible. When the user scrolls, the adapter creates the required views dynamically based on the data structure you give it.

Comment: A very simple example of adapter usage is as follows:

ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.<id of your listview>);
ArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(context, <layout resource to inflate>, <your list data structure>);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

You can create your own adapter to override certain things if you want to as well. Here is the documentation for ArrayAdapter:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

I also recommend watching some youtube videos to further your understanding. SlideNerd has some great ones!

Comment: @lamatat Please mark this question as 'Answered'. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Add the listeners for the button in the BaseAdapter class. Below is an example code. Here I am performing some actions if a button is clicked in the listview.

```
public class People_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private ImageButton delete_contact;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size() / 2;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null)
        {
           convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my list_item_2, parent, false);
           delete_contact = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.excl_ppl_delete);

           delete_contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                      //Add code here what needs to be done onclick
               });  
        }


        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: or there is no need for calling the adapter class ?